# Cannot make my div tag mobile responsive

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I'm building a site with coupon codes and so far, I'm satisfied with how it look in desktop but it looks horrible when I view it in my smartphone. What I want to achieve is for this div to display 100% wide in smartphone while remaining 70% in desktop view. Here is the code I used:

```
 <div class="couponr" style="width: 80%; padding: 10px; text-align: center; border: 5px dashed red; margin:auto ">  
   <h3>
   <span style="background-color:#ffffff;"><strong>HELLOCAVITE</strong></span>
  </h3>
  <hr />
  <h3>
    P100 Off on 5 Rides!
  </h3>     
   Copy the coupon above at checkout to redeem P100 off from Uber.
 </div>
```

Check out this sample output [here](http://www.techaways.tk/uber-promo-code-p100-off-5-uber-trips-cavite/) It looks okay in desktop but ugly in smaller screens. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

you need grid based layout to work on, choose how your content looks on different screens. You can use bootstrap or foundation for that or you can create your own grid based layout. Learn more about responsive web design.

Answer (score 0):

Erase the complete `style` attribute from the `.couponr` tag and write something like this into your CSS stylesheet:

```
.couponr {
  width: 70%; 
  padding: 10px; 
  text-align: center; 
  border: 5px dashed red; 
  margin:auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .couponr {
   width: 100%;
 }
}
```

P.S.: The `.coupnr` tag would then simply be

```
<div class="couponr">
```

(i.e. no `style` attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing just remove you width from your couponr div you will get responsive auto width.
At your site.

```
<div class="couponr" style="padding: 10px; text-align: center; border: 5px dashed red; margin:auto ">  
   <h3>
   <span style="background-color:#ffffff;"><strong>HELLOCAVITE</strong></span>
  </h3>
  <hr />
  <h3>
    P100 Off on 5 Rides!
  </h3>     
   Copy the coupon above at checkout to redeem P100 off from Uber.
 </div>
```

[image: Dextop_view]
[image: Mobile_view]